# An Inequalitiy in Holder Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading the Schauder estimates for the Poisson equation. However, I got stuck at proving this inequality.

For every $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists $Q(\epsilon)$ such that for all $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(B(0,1))$
\begin{equation}
||u||_{C^2(B(0,1))}\le \epsilon ||u||_{C^{2,\alpha}(B(0,1))}+Q(\epsilon)||u||_{L^2(B(0,1))}
\end{equation}
Where 
\begin{equation}
Q(\epsilon)\le c\epsilon^{-d-1-\alpha},
\end{equation}
c is a constant not depending on $\epsilon$. The problem is that I can not get the bound for $Q(\epsilon)$. Can anyone please help me ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $d$ the dimension of the space?

Comment: Yes. We are working on $R^d$